# Using a partial from another view while that model's routes are nested in the current view Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I've got two models/views, `User` and `PersonalInfo` and I'm trying to call the `_form.html.erb` partial in the `'user#show'` action, but I'm getting an error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"personal_info"}`

I suspect the issue is that my `PersonalInfo` routes are nested within the `User` routes and Rails isn't using the right one, but I don't know how to make it use the right one. Here's the line that's calling the form:

`app/views/users/show.html.erb`:

`<%= render :partial => "/personal_info/form", :locals => {personal_info: @personal_info } %>`

`app/views/personal_info/_form.html.erb`:

`<%= form_for @personal_info, url: user_personal_info_index_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`

`routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  resources :personal_info
end
```

Do I either have to declare something in the personal_info controller or specify the app to use the `users/:user_id/personal_info` route?

Comment: Given that your `personal_info` controller is at `app/controllers`, you can add the `controller` option to the `resources` declaration in `routes.rb` as: `resources :personal_info, controller: 'personal_infos'`

Comment: @vinodadhikary I still end up getting the same error message, but I think I'm referencing something wrong somewhere..

Comment: In your `form_for` declaration for `url` you also need to pass in `user_id`, i.e `<%= form_for @personal_info, url: user_personal_info_index_path(@user), html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`.  Please initiate a chat request if this does not work.  Also it appears to me that your `resources :personal_info` should be `resources :personal_infos`(plural).

Comment: @vinodadhikary -- I don't know that I can use the chat system (I have less than 20 reputation), but using what you listed, I'm still getting an error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"personal_infos", :user_id`  and the :user_id has a hash of the user object attributes after it.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved by changing `<%= form_for @personal_info, url: user_personal_info_index_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @personal_info, url: new_user_personal_info_index_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved by changing:
    `<%= form_for @personal_info, url: user_personal_info_index_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`

to:

`<%= form_for @personal_info, url: new_user_personal_info_index_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>`